# Regex Capture a matching group twice

Tags: python, regex

I have been looking at a lot of questions but none of them answered my problem.

I am trying to identify vanity/special mobile numbers consisting of 9 digits.

I have this pattern of two numbers repeating for 4 times each

```
5XXXXYYYY
```

I was able to write a regex that catches the first group 'XXXX'. However, I am not able to acpture the second one 'YYYY'.

This is the regex I have tried so far

```
(\d)\1{3}

[0-9]{4,5}
```

I tried it on the below number, it returns '1111' and ignores '2222'

```
511112222
```

Is there a way to repeat the capture to include both groups

Thank you

Comment: Are you using `re.finditer` or `re.search`? Use `re.finditer` to get all matches.

Comment: Maybe you can reach with this way `result.group(1)` or `result.group(2)`. 1111 takes in place first gruop and 2222 should be in the second group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^5((\d)\2{3})((\d)\4{3})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ozpKO/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `5`: Match `5`
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(\d)`: Match a digit in capture group #2
  - `\2{3}`: Repeat value captured in group #2 exactly 3 times
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `(`: Start capture group #3

  - `(\d)`: Match a digit in capture group #4
  - `\4{3}`: Repeat value captured in group #4 exactly 3 times
- `)`: End capture group #3
- `$`: End